# Adding diamonds to the line between nodes in Forest diagrams

Tags: forest

I would like to be able to add an optional diamond and a 'curvy arrow' in the below diagram. I was thinking of trying to put `tikz` commnads in the `forest` environment but that doesn't seem to work. An example would be something like this:
[image]

```
    \begin{forest}
        for tree=draw,
        [Main(), [Level Setup],[Game], [Win_Game()]]
    \end{forest}
```

This is what I have for now, and I noted a code snippet I found with `edge label={node[midway,left,font=\scriptsize]{text}}`, which would give the labels on the arrows I would want to draw, but do not draw the arrow.

Comment: Welcome. // Please avoid posting code fragments only from now on: nobody likes to reverse-engineer such code. Standard here is to provide code, which compiles, is minimal AND shows your problem (and own attempts). Thank you (Your fragment did not compile even after good will activities wrt your code ...)

Comment: So sorry. I'll make sure to not do this again. Is there a link to a 'checklist' I can use when asking questions as to be specific?

Comment: There are some links to useful Meta questions at https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/often-referenced-questions/6581#6581. However, I thought there would be something more to the point regarding MWEs. One link focuses on reducing code. The other doesn't really deal with the details of what code to post at all. A question should include code I can copy, paste and (try to) compile. If the question is about an error, it should include the error and the code should produce that error; otherwise the code should compile and the question should explain what concrete thing is a problem.

Comment: (Usually. Some questions are conceptual.) You could ask on Meta if there's a checklist. (A *concise* checklist - not an essay.)

Comment: @apathyy, no problem. To my knowledge there are several questions/treads, dealing with MWEs, like this one: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/245790 . I'm not aware of a checklist, so I posted one there together with an example: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10137/245790 .

Comment: Thank you both :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a version with some styles you can modify or reuse as required. I started from [MS-SPO's code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/703008/) because it compiled.

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/703039/ addaswyd o ateb MS-SPO: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/703008/ i gwestiwn apathyy: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/702992/
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shapes.geometric}    % to modify arrow tips, see ch. 16.5 pfgmanual
\forestset{%
  from diamond/.style={%
    before typesetting nodes={%
      replace by={%
        [,
          diamond, 
          inner sep=1.5pt, 
          no edge, 
          anchor=north, 
          draw, 
          append,
          before drawing tree={%
            y'=0pt,
            if={>Od>{x}{0pt}}{x'=10pt}{x'=-10pt},
          },
        ]%
      },
    },
  },
  branch arrows/.style args={from #1 to #2 with label #3 and from #4 to #5 with label #6}{%
    edge label+/.process={Ow{name}{coordinate [pos=#1] (##1-a) coordinate [pos=#2] (##1-b) coordinate [pos=#4] (##1-c) coordinate [pos=#5] (##1-d)}},
    tikz+/.process={Ow{name}{%
        \draw [{Circle[open]}-Stealth,very thin] (##1-c) ++(0pt,2.5pt) -- ([yshift=2.5pt]##1-d) node [above,my branch arrow label] {#3};
        \draw [{Circle[open]}-Stealth,very thin] (##1-b) ++(0pt,-2.5pt) -- ([yshift=-2.5pt]##1-a) node [below,my branch arrow label] {#6};
      }%
    },
  },
  trunk arrows/.style args={from #1 to #2 with label #3 and from #4 to #5 with label #6}{%
    edge label+/.process={Ow{name}{coordinate [pos=#1] (##1-a) coordinate [pos=#2] (##1-b) coordinate [pos=#4] (##1-c) coordinate [pos=#5] (##1-d)}},
    tikz+/.process={Ow{name}{%
        \draw [{Circle[open]}-Stealth,very thin] (##1-c) ++(2.5pt,0pt) -- ([xshift=2.5pt]##1-d) node [right,my arrow label] {#3};
        \draw [{Circle[open]}-Stealth,very thin] (##1-b) ++(-2.5pt,0pt) -- ([xshift=-2.5pt]##1-a) node [left,my arrow label] {#6};
      }%
    },
  },
  apathyy tree/.style={%
    for tree={%
      draw,
      fit=band,
      s sep'+=20pt,
      delay={content+=\strut},
      font=\sffamily,
    },
    for descendants={anchor=north,
      tier/.option=level,
    },
    anchor=south,
  },
  /tikz/my arrow label/.style={midway,font=\sffamily\tiny,inner sep=1pt,},
  /tikz/my branch arrow label/.style={/tikz/my arrow label,sloped},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  apathyy tree,
  [Main()
    [Level Setup, 
      {fill=blue!20}, 
      from diamond,
      branch arrows=from 0.125 to 0.525 with label {text} and from 0.575 to 0.975 with label {other},
      [nested 1
        [nested 1.1]
        [nested 1.2
          [nested 1.2.1
            [nested 1.2.2]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]   % just put some color
    [Game,
      calign with current edge,
      trunk arrows=from 0.9 to 0.4 with label {label} and from 0.95 to 0.1 with label {extra},
      [nested 1]
      [nested 2]
    ]       % this tree only with ordinary lines
    [Win\_Game(), 
      from diamond,
      branch arrows=from 0.125 to 0.525 with label {more} and from 0.575 to 0.975 with label {another},
      [nested 1
        [nested 1.1]
      ]
    ]                   % you need to backslash the underscore
  ]
  \draw [-Stealth] (!r1.west) ..controls +(-25pt,-5pt) and +(-5pt,0pt).. ([yshift=-4pt]!r.center |- !r1.south) ..controls +(5pt,0pt) and +(25pt,-5pt).. (!r3.east);
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: apathyy tree with arrowed styling]

### EDIT

Here's a somewhat more flexible version. It doesn't change how you add diamonds etc., but it should do a better job of placing things by default.

[image: more diamonds and arrows]

To add a diamond, you just add `from diamond` to the child, as before.

The curved arrows are just regular Ti*k*Z commands added after the tree is drawn. I've added two further examples.

- The simplest method is just to name the node you want, as I do with `wingame`.
- However, this isn't straightforward for the diamonds, so I've used `forest` node names for those. Basically, the `!` indicates a 'walk' through the tree to a node. `r` is the root. `1` is the first child, `2` the second and so on.
- So `(!r1.west)` is the diamond node at the top of the branch leading to the 'Level Setup' node.
- `(!r21.west)` is the west anchor of the first child of the second child of the root i.e. the diamond at the start of the branch from 'Game' to 'nested 1'.

Note that the following code uses a custom argument processor because I couldn't get the standard processors to do what I wanted. As far as I know, there is no official way to do this, so the definition uses internal macros. This means you can't blame `forest`'s author if a package update breaks that bit. (You probably should blame me rather than `forest`'s author anyway, but the definition of `q` is certainly unsanctioned.)

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/703039/ addaswyd o ateb MS-SPO: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/703008/ i gwestiwn apathyy: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/702992/
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shapes.geometric}    % to modify arrow tips, see ch. 16.5 pfgmanual
\makeatletter
\forest@def@processor{q}{}{}{%
  \forest@process@left@toppop\forest@temp
  \forest@process@left@toppop\forest@tempa
  \forest@process@left@toppop\forest@tempb
  \ifnum\forest@temp=0
    \forest@process@right@letprepend\forest@tempb
  \else
    \forest@process@right@letprepend\forest@tempa
  \fi
  \let\forestmathresulttype\forestmathtype@generic
}
\makeatother
\forestset{%
  declare dimen={parental width share}{-1000pt},
  declare boolean={is from diamond}{0},
  declare boolean={is diamond}{0},
  from diamond/.style={%
    is from diamond,
    before typesetting nodes={%
      replace by={%
        [,
          diamond, 
          is diamond,
          inner sep=1.5pt, 
          no edge, 
          anchor=north, 
          draw, 
          append,
          before drawing tree={%
            if={ >Od= {!u.parental width share}{-1000pt}}{
              !u.parental width share/.process={ OOOw3+P w+d d S2 l2 > q {!u.max x}{!u.min x}{!u.n children}{(##1-##2)/(##3-1)} {##1pt} {10pt} },
              for siblings={%
                if={>OO|{is diamond}{is from diamond}}{}{%
                  edge path'/.process={OOOw3+Pw {n}{!u.n children}{!u.parental width share}{(##1-((##2+1)/2))*##3} {(!u.south) ++(##1pt,0pt) -- (.child anchor)}},
                },
              },
            }{},
            y/.option=!u.y,
            y+/.option=!u.min y,
            x/.process={ OOOw3+P {n}{!u.n children}{!u.parental width share}{(##1-((##2+1)/2))*##3}},
          },
        ]%
      },
    },
  },
  branch arrows/.style args={from #1 to #2 with label #3 and from #4 to #5 with label #6}{%
    edge label+/.process={Ow{name}{coordinate [pos=#1] (##1-a) coordinate [pos=#2] (##1-b) coordinate [pos=#4] (##1-c) coordinate [pos=#5] (##1-d)}},
    tikz+/.process={Ow{name}{%
        \draw [{Circle[open]}-Stealth,very thin] (##1-c) ++(0pt,2.5pt) -- ([yshift=2.5pt]##1-d) node [above,my branch arrow label] {#3};
        \draw [{Circle[open]}-Stealth,very thin] (##1-b) ++(0pt,-2.5pt) -- ([yshift=-2.5pt]##1-a) node [below,my branch arrow label] {#6};
      }%
    },
  },
  trunk arrows/.style args={from #1 to #2 with label #3 and from #4 to #5 with label #6}{%
    edge label+/.process={Ow{name}{coordinate [pos=#1] (##1-a) coordinate [pos=#2] (##1-b) coordinate [pos=#4] (##1-c) coordinate [pos=#5] (##1-d)}},
    tikz+/.process={Ow{name}{%
        \draw [{Circle[open]}-Stealth,very thin] (##1-c) ++(2.5pt,0pt) -- ([xshift=2.5pt]##1-d) node [right,my arrow label] {#3};
        \draw [{Circle[open]}-Stealth,very thin] (##1-b) ++(-2.5pt,0pt) -- ([xshift=-2.5pt]##1-a) node [left,my arrow label] {#6};
      }%
    },
  },
  apathyy tree/.style={%
    for tree={%
      draw,
      fit=band,
      s sep'+=20pt,
      delay={content+=\strut},
      font=\sffamily,
    },
    for descendants={anchor=north,
      tier/.option=level,
    },
    anchor=south,
  },
  /tikz/my arrow label/.style={midway,font=\sffamily\tiny,inner sep=1pt,},
  /tikz/my branch arrow label/.style={/tikz/my arrow label,sloped},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  apathyy tree,
  [Main()
    [Level Setup, 
      {fill=blue!20}, 
      from diamond,
      branch arrows=from 0.125 to 0.525 with label {text} and from 0.575 to 0.975 with label {other},
      [nested 1
        [nested 1.1]
        [nested 1.2
          [nested 1.2.1
            [nested 1.2.2]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]   % just put some color
    [Game,
      calign with current edge,
      trunk arrows=from 0.9 to 0.4 with label {label} and from 0.95 to 0.1 with label {extra},
      [nested 1, from diamond]
      [nested 2, from diamond]
      [nested 3, from diamond]
      [nested 4]
      [nested 5, from diamond]
    ]       % this tree only with ordinary lines
    [Win\_Game(), name=wingame,
      from diamond,
      branch arrows=from 0.125 to 0.525 with label {more} and from 0.575 to 0.975 with label {another},
      [nested 1
        [nested 1.1]
      ]
    ]                   % you need to backslash the underscore
  ]
  \draw [-Stealth] (!r1.west) ..controls +(-25pt,-5pt) and +(-5pt,0pt).. ([yshift=-4pt]!r.center |- !r1.south) ..controls +(5pt,0pt) and +(25pt,-5pt).. (!r3.east);
  \draw [-Stealth] (!r21.west) ..controls +(-25pt,-5pt) and +(-5pt,0pt).. ([yshift=-4pt]!r2.center |- !r21.south) ..controls +(5pt,0pt) and +(25pt,-5pt).. (!r25.east);
  \draw [-Stealth] (wingame.west) ..controls +(-35pt,-10pt) and +(-15pt,0pt).. ([yshift=-5pt]wingame.south) ..controls +(15pt,0pt) and +(35pt,-10pt).. (wingame.east);
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

### EDIT 2

You can change the styles `/tikz/my arrow label` and/or `/tikz/my branch arrow label` using any standard Ti*k*Z keys. These aren't Forest styles (and you actually can't use Forest keys in them). So adding something like `align=center` to those styles will let you use `\\`  in labels. Or `textwidth=<dimension>` will make the label wrap lines to the given width. If you want a lot of parallel arrows, you could create specialised styles. Or you can just add them at the end of the Forest environment.

For example, suppose we change the definition of `my arrow label` (which will also alter `my branch arrow label`) to

```
  /tikz/my arrow label/.style={midway,font=\sffamily\tiny,inner sep=1pt,align=center},
```

and we add

```
  \draw [{Circle[open]}-Stealth,very thin] (wingame-a) ++(0pt,10pt) -- ([yshift=10pt]wingame-d) node [above,my branch arrow label] {parallel\\multiline};
```

before `\end{forest}`. Then we'll get a two-lined label with an additional arrow to the `wingame` node.

[image: additional arrow with multiline label to wingame]

Arrows drawn like this are parallel, but their start and end points won't align because I've not allowed for the angle of the `edge`. All I've done is shifted the arrow upwards. If you wanted to, you could presumably account for this angle, but hopefully it shouldn't be too critical in most cases because you aren't moving the arrow too far.

Comment: When I try to add extra levels, the middle block (Game) isn't inline with the rest (it's above). I've tried changing the `anchor` and `align` settings but the only thing that seems to work is manually using a `yshift` on the middle block. Sorry for not including this in the first question and or if it should be a standalone.

Comment: @apathyy Where are you adding levels? I fiddled this so the diamonds didn't align with `Game`. So it probably needs a different fiddle. Or just to be rethought if you want to repeat it. I was mostly focused on arrows. Maybe we should use an arrow tip for the diamonds as MS-SPO does?

Comment: I was adding nested items within Level Setup, Game and Win_Game

Comment: @apathyy Like this? (See edited code/image above.)

Comment: Yes! How would you add the diamond to the start of any node connector i.e between Game and Nested 1? And adding the curved arrow say, in win_game(what is `r1`?)

Comment: @apathyy Please see edit. I assume you mean `!r1` as `r1` doesn't refer to anything ;).

Comment: thank you so much!

Comment: @apathyy When you've figured out what you're using, please consider accepting one of the answers to your question as this helps other users find solutions on the site. To do this, you click on the greyed-out tick symbol at the top left of the answer you want to accept. [Disclaimer: accepting an answer gives its author 'points' and you also get 'points' for accepting one.]

Comment: Yep! I've done that. Again, thank you :)

Comment: @apathyy You're welcome ;).

Comment: One more tidbit - is it possible to 'stack' arrows on top of each other – like two parallel arrows with different `label`s (e.g another arrow text, parallel and above the first arrow text from Main) or multi line label? (

Comment: @apathyy Please see edit.

Comment: Thank you again! In the line `\draw [{Circle[open]}-Stealth,very thin] (wingame-a) ++(0pt,10pt) -- ([yshift=10pt]wingame-d) node [above,my branch arrow label] {parallel\\multiline};`, what do `wingame-a` and `-wingame-d` refer to? Is it similar to say, a node's `west` or `east` positions?

Comment: @apathyy In the definitions of `trunk arrows` and `branch arrows`, 4 coordinates are defined. Each uses the name of the current forest node with a `-<letter>` suffix. These are just created at positions along the edge from the node to its parent. So `wingame-a`, `wingame-b`, `wingame-c` and `wingame-d` refer to positions along the edge from `wingame`'s parent to `wingame`. These coordinates are then used to place the arrows.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it:

- please skim through the [forest manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/forest)
- please skim through the pgfmanual, e.g. the [arrow library](https://tikz.dev/library-arrows)

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}    % to modify arrow tips, see ch. 16.5 pfgmanual

\begin{document}
 \begin{forest}
    for tree={draw,edge={Turned Square[open]}-}% all start with a gem
    [Main()
        [Level Setup, {fill=blue!20}]   % just put some color
        [Game, for tree={edge=-}]       % this tree only with ordinary lines
        [Win\_Game()]                   % you need to backslash the underscore
    ]
 \end{forest}
\end{document}
```